# Hyperbolic coordinates (Poincaré embeddings) as the output of a neural network

Tags: keras, neural-network

I'm trying to build a Deep Learning predictor that takes as the input a set of word vectors (in Euclidian space) and outputs Poincaré embeddings. So far I am not having much luck, because model predicts arbitrary points in the n-dimensional real space, not the hyperbolic space. This causes the distance, and thus the loss function to be undefined. Therefore I need to restrict the output of the model somehow. I have tried several things.

First was defining the loss function that minimizes the Hyperbolic distance (on the Poincaré hyperdisc):

```
def distance_loss(u, v):
    max_norm = 1 - K.epsilon()

    sq_u_norm = K.clip(K.sum(K.pow(u, 2), axis=-1), 0, max_norm)
    sq_v_norm = K.clip(K.sum(K.pow(v, 2), axis=-1), 0, max_norm)

    sq_dist = K.sum(K.pow(u - v, 2), axis=-1)
    poincare_dist = tf.acosh(1 + (sq_dist / ((1 - sq_u_norm) * (1 - sq_v_norm))) * 2)
    neg_exp_dist = K.exp(-poincare_dist)
    return -K.log(neg_exp_dist)
```

Which I somewhat dumbly lifted from [here](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/poincare.py#L324) and [here](https://github.com/kousun12/tf_hyperbolic).

However that doesn't seem to work properly on it's own. Next up was to change the optimizer to something I lifted from [a notebook](https://github.com/kmkolasinski/deep-learning-notes/blob/master/seminars/2017-09-Poincare-Embeddings/notebooks/optimizers.py) on the topic, and [some slides (PDF)](https://github.com/kmkolasinski/deep-learning-notes/blob/master/seminars/2017-09-Poincare-Embeddings/slides.pdf). Note that I am using Keras 2.1.6 with Tensorflow, so I had to make some changes.

```
def get_normalization(p):
    p_norm = K.sum(K.square(p), -1, keepdims=True)
    mp = K.square(1 - p_norm)/4.0
    return mp, K.sqrt(p_norm)


def project(p, p_norm):
    p_norm_clip = K.maximum(p_norm, 1.0)
    p_norm_cond = K.cast(p_norm > 1.0, dtype='float') * K.epsilon()
    return p/p_norm_clip - p_norm_cond

class AdamPoincare(Adam):
    @interfaces.legacy_get_updates_support
    def get_updates(self,loss,params):
        grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
        self.updates = [K.update_add(self.iterations, 1)]

        lr = self.lr
        if self.initial_decay > 0:
            lr = lr * (1. / (1. + self.decay * K.cast(self.iterations,
                                                      K.dtype(self.decay))))

        t = K.cast(self.iterations, K.floatx()) + 1
        lr_t = lr * (K.sqrt(1. - K.pow(self.beta_2, t)) /
                     (1. - K.pow(self.beta_1, t)))

        ms = [K.zeros(K.int_shape(p), dtype=K.dtype(p)) for p in params]
        vs = [K.zeros(K.int_shape(p), dtype=K.dtype(p)) for p in params]

        self.weights = [self.iterations] + ms + vs

        for p, g, m, v in zip(params, grads, ms, vs):

            normalization, p_norm = get_normalization(p)
            g = normalization * g

            m_t = (self.beta_1 * m) + (1. - self.beta_1) * g
            v_t = (self.beta_2 * v) + (1. - self.beta_2) * K.square(g)
            p_t = p - lr_t * m_t / (K.sqrt(v_t) + self.epsilon)

            self.updates.append(K.update(m, m_t))
            self.updates.append(K.update(v, v_t))

            new_p = project(p_t, p_norm)

            # Apply constraints.
            if getattr(p, 'constraint', None) is not None:
                new_p = p.constraint(new_p)

            self.updates.append(K.update(p, new_p))
        return self.updates
```

That also still didn't do what I wanted, so lastly I tried to add a lambda layer that on the forward pass projects the points (although I have no idea if this proper). The target outputs are already coordinates in Hyperbolic space (so on the backward pass this should be a no-op).

```
def poincare_project(x, axis=-1):
    square_sum = K.tf.reduce_sum(
        K.tf.square(x), axis, keepdims=True)
    x_inv_norm = K.tf.rsqrt(square_sum)
    x_inv_norm = K.tf.minimum((1. - K.epsilon()) * x_inv_norm, 1.)
    outputs = K.tf.multiply(x, x_inv_norm)
    return outputs


x_dense = Dense(int(params["semantic_dense"]))(x_activation)
x_activation = activation(x_dense)
x_output = Dense(params["semantic_dim"], activation="tanh")(x_activation)
x_project = Lambda(poincare_project)(x_output)
```

But it still produces garbage results (doesn't minimize the distance, or causes NaN/Inf on subsequent evaluation). Now there might be a bug in any of these implementations, or the whole idea is just invalid. I can't really tell right now. The concrete goal is a form of supervised entity linking, where the input is a target word in a context, and the output is a point in the Poincare embedding representing a structured ontology.

I did find a [paper](https://www.groundai.com/project/embedding-text-in-hyperbolic-spaces/1)([pdf](https://aclweb.org/anthology/W18-1708)) that tried to do this, by reparameterizing the model, but I wasn't able to gauge from their description how to implement this. It does describe the problem neatly though.

[image: the problem]

Comment: I am curious if you ever go this to work. I am running into similar issues that you describe here where model does learn and generalize well (compared to random), yet the predictions themselves are not quite useful or accurate, i.e., predicting the poincare vector and looking up the closest 'true' vector is nowhere close to true category.